# Can't force external terminal to open in current directory in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I open an *external* terminal in the current project directory?
I want to open a `wsl` session (when I invoke `open external terminal`) but it keeps opening in `Microsoft VS Code` folder

[image]

My setting is as follow:

```json
{
  "terminal.external.windowsExec": "wsl.exe"
}
```

I tried passing an argument

```json
{
  "terminal.external.windowsExec": "wsl.exe -d ${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

But vscode doesn't like that.

What am I missing?

Comment: cannot reproduce the issue. not sure why. when I set `"terminal.external.windowsExec": "wsl.exe"`, it opens with cwd in the workspace folder by default. I can reproduce the error when passing `-d ${workspaceFolder}`. can you give as much info as possible about your system, wsl, and wsl distro installation? did you do a [user setup or system setup](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows#_user-setup-versus-system-setup)?